# Define an object extending PartialFunction, implement directly with cases

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I'm quite new to Scala but I already love it. I have read tutorials and articles on partial functions. What I would like to achieve is to have an object extending PartialFunction[...,...] and have it defined directly with cases, without needing to define isDefinedAt and apply methods.

For example

```
val partialfuncval : PartialFunction[Int,Boolean] = {
    case 1 => false
}
```

is a valid definition of a partial function. But why can't I write

```
object PartialFunctionClass extends PartialFunction[Int,Boolean] {
    case 1 => false
}
```

? This would cancel the need of defining isDefinedAt and apply and would make writing classes of certain (predefined by a lib I'm using) types easier.

Comment: I know, this would disallow the definition of other members of this class, but in this special case, it would actually make things easier. Should I request this lang feature? Or is this achievable in a way I don't know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would one of these options suffice you?

**Option 1**

```
abstract class DelegatingPartialFunction[-T,+R](underlying: PartialFunction[T,R]) extends PartialFunction[T,R] {
  def apply(t: T) = underlying.apply(t)
  def isDefinedAt(t: T) = underlying.isDefinedAt(t)
}
```

Then:

```
object PartialFunctionClass extends DelegatingPartialFunction[Int,Boolean]({
  case 1 => false
})
```

**Option 2**

```
trait DelegatingPartialFunction[-T,+R] extends PartialFunction[T,R] {
  val underlying: PartialFunction[T,R]
  def apply(t: T) = underlying.apply(t)
  def isDefinedAt(t: T) = underlying.isDefinedAt(t)
}
```

Then:

```
object PartialFunctionClass extends DelegatingPartialFunction[Int,Boolean] {
  val underlying = {
    case 1 => true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might work depending on the use-case is

```
type PartialFunctionAlias = PartialFunction[Int,Boolean]
```

Then:

```
val partialfuncval: PartialFunctionAlias = {
  case 1 => false
}
```